# Bayes Network/Conditional Probability Visualization Tools

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-visualization, bayesian-network, interactive-visualization

I'm hoping that someone could suggest a tool for viewing conditional probabilities withi.  I am currently using Weka, but the ability to view the conditional probability tables of nodes within the Network is not the easiest to read.

Any suggestions on tools out there, or perhaps a workflow in R that can help with this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider trying SamIam: http://reasoning.cs.ucla.edu/samiam/

It's a Java-based tool that allows detailed specification of Bayes networks and associated CPDs.

I'm not an expert, so this may not be exactly what you had in mind.

Greetings

Comment: +1 for samiam. This is the tool we used in the introductory lessons of the Stanford class on Probabilistic Graphical Models. It is nicely suited to viewing conditional probabilities and seeing how they change as different variables are observed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple tool in HTML5 (a Venn Pie Chart) that might help to visualize conditional probabilities and Bayes' theorem:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/133074120/venn_pie_solver.html