# Binary output recommender system: Bayesian network vs Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, bayesian-network

I am going to build a recommender system. My projects determines a binary output.

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using a Bayesian network instead of a Neural Network?

My data set has around 10k observations with around 20-30 features within. It is a time series with a duration of a few months.

Comment: Your question is too imprecise at this stage. Can you specify the structure of your data, the nature of your inference, and if possible the statistical model behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> People who do Bayes network say it's best, could not have any advice
>   on NN

I doubt any statement regarding the performance of the model can be reliable as long as they have not been tested against the data.

In your case, I would consider two factors to make my choice.

**Feasibility**

> 10k examples with around 20-30 features

It is not a big amount of data. On a very large scale, neural network still have a good (low) training time. Here, you should be able to run both models.

**Interpretable model**

Bayes network will provide you nice visualization of your data (see per example [Bayes Network/Conditional Probability Visualization Tools](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27406/bayes-network-conditional-probability-visualization-tools)). It will be harder with neural networks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really helps me ! If we consider increasing the number of examples (we will get more and more data within the next month), would it be a better idea to consider NN in that case ? Or should we stick with Bayes network ?

Comment: @AntoineSauray my experience with Bayes networkk is rather limited... It really depends on the extent of the number of new samples. If the magnitude remains the same (10k -> 20k) don't worry. If you end up with 1M+ of observations, a lot of things will stop being feasible...